# Simplify Python code?

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a Python script which downloads every picture of an array which is full of links.

The code looks like this:

```
for url in array:
    if 'jpg' in url or 'jpeg' in url or 'png' in url or 'gif' in url:
        print url
```

As you can see, the if statement is pretty inefficient and I'd like to simplify it. Preferably with a regex if it's possible there. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com for review of working code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regex is not the right tool for this because you are not matching patterns, just looking for substrings.

Instead, you should use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
if any(x in url for x in ('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif')):
```

As a bonus, this solution is lazy like your current one (it only performas as many `in` membership tests as needed)

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not the same, it is more what you intend to do:

```
for url in array:
    if url.rsplit('.',1)[1] in ('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'):
        print url
```

Answer (score 2):

You may not need regex to do this but if you still want to, here's a way:

http://regex101.com/r/jH8fO4/3 <-- see the regex in action.

`^.*\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$`

you can of course add more to the end of the expression in order to handle cases where there's a request or variable attached to the url.

edit - updated to comply with the possibility of more than 1 dot in the filename:

http://regex101.com/r/jH8fO4/4 `^[a-z0-9]*\.{1}(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$`

Comment: i'll try to handle that case but that isn't a strictly _invalid_ filename, so I don't know if it'd be a necessary check.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same thing using regular expressions would look something like this.

```
pattern = re.compile('jpg|jpeg|png|gif')

for url in array:
    if pattern.search(url) is not None:
        print url
```

Comment: This will match urls like `mygif.com/index.html`. Although the original problem will match those urls too, we only want to match the extensions if they're at the end of the url.

Comment: The OP asked if his code could be done using regexes. Of course you could improve it, but that's not what was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I would use os.path.splitext:

```
import os
for url in array:
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(url)
    if ext in ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif'):
        print url
```